# How to read namespaced tag "<a:a>" from XML in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Am trying to use XSLT for my **XML** given below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a:catalog>
<a:cd>
    <a:title>Empire Burlesque</a:title>
    <a:artist>Bob Dylan</a:artist>
    <a:country>USA</a:country>

</a:cd>
<a:cd>
    <a:title>Hide your heart</a:title>
    <a:artist>Bonnie Tyler</a:artist>
    <a:country>UK</a:country>
</a:cd>
</a:catalog>
```

And below id my **XSLT** which am trying to run to fetch `a:title` and `a:artist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
  <h2>My test XSLT</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="a:catalog/a:cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="a:title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="a:artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this without namespace I can get output but not with namespace. 
Or should I write **code for remove namespaces** from XML ?

Comment: You need to map the namespace prefixed with `a` in the XSL also. The XML that you have shared does not show any namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both your XML and your XSLT have to declare all namespaces in use.**

(No, do ***not*** write code to remove the namespaces.  Namespaces play a valuable role in XML vocabulary definition and management.)

Instead, add a namespace declaration, such as

```
xmlns:a="http://example.com/a"
```

to the root elements in your XML and XSLT files.

Note that to use a namespace prefix in an XML document without defining it prevents the XML document from being [***namespace-well-formed***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).

Comment: Yes, @kjhughes, this worked for me.One more related question that if i have same xml format with different nested namespaces like below then ?


__<a0:catalog>
<a2:cd>
    <a1:title>Empire Burlesque</a:title>
</a2:cd>
<a2:cd>
    <a1:title>Hide your heart</a:title>
</a2:cd>
</a0:catalog>__

Comment: All used namespace prefixes must be declared as shown in this answer.  Note that it is the binding to a namespace URI that gives the prefix its meaning, not the prefix itself.  This means that if `a0` and `a1` are both bound to `http://example.com/a`, then `a0:x` and `a1:x` are the same names.

Comment: Is this i have to add in xsl root elements for  __xmlns:a2=" http://example.com/a2" xmlns:a0=" http://example.com/a0" xmlns:a1=" http://example.com/a1"__

Comment: And in your XML too, yes.

Comment: Thank you for solution and provided info for XML Document  "namespace-well-formed"